# How to reinitialize (recall) FancyBox after AJAX updated DOM?

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I'm using widgetkit plugin (Joomla CMS), for lightbox. Since widgetkit uses fancybox to display lightbox im posting a question here.

FancyBox works great when i'm not using AJAX technology to update the content of the Joomla website. When i enable AJAX, and refresh or move to another page using ajax technology lightbox effect is gone - the image itself opens in a new window. I think this is because AJAX updates the DOM and FancyBox doesn't recognize that. I do have in the plugin of AJAX code an area, where i can write certain JavaScript code, that will AJAX execute after the website is fully loaded by AJAX. 
I'm just wondering what should i type in there, to initialize the FancyBox to the new DOM, that AJAX just generated.

For mootools lightbox (if i had it) i could simply write this line: window.fireEvent('domready');

I don't know how to do that for jQuery FancyBox.

I also posted the same question here (if anyone needs more information): http://skrij.me/Qv56

Answer (score 2):

You either call fancybox (e.g., `$(".fancybox").fancybox();`) each time you make changes to the DOM or use version 2 that uses "live" to attach click handler

Comment: Well the selector for images i use on url is: <a data-lightbox="on" src=....><img.... /></a> So i tried putting FLAX.Html.onall('load', function(o){  
        $("a[data-lightbox]").fancybox();
  
}); and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create fucntion for initialize fancybox e.g.

```
function fancybox_init(){
        $("a[href*='.jpg'], a[href*='.png']").attr('rel', 'fancybox').fancybox({
            maxWidth  : 800,
            maxHeight : 600,
            fitToView : true,
            width     : '70%',
            height    : '70%',
            autoSize  : true,
            closeClick    : false,
            openEffect    : 'none',
            closeEffect   : 'none'
        });
    }
```

And then after ajax reload page or adding new block simply call this function in success callback of ajax method