# fancybox2 not working on second call on ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, live, fancybox-2

i have a multiple products page if one is selected the php for that product gets loaded onto the div replacing the multiple products - i use the fancybox plugin for the gallery of images of the selected product. when I select a product and click on any of the images, it flawlessly shows the fancybox gallery. but when i go back and select a second product it just does not open ...

the pagemap is as follows-
products page
contains 2(named type1 and type2) buttons and 1(dynamic div)
the products page loads type1.php on loading

the buttons use the following ajax

```
$('div#type1_link').on('click',function() {         
        $('div#ajax_div').html("<img src='ajax-load.gif' />").load("type1.php?carmodel=" + $for_url);
        });
```

i use fancybox like

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox();//for initialisation

<a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="images/<?php echo $row2['img1'] ?>">
    <img src="images/thumbs/<?php echo $row2['img1'] ?>"></a></li>//on images
```

please tell a way i can fix this problem.
using latest fancybox and jquery versions

Comment: also while checking i noticed that on the second ajax call

the following div does get added in the DOM
`<div class="fancybox-overlay fancybox-overlay-fixed" style="width: auto; height: auto; display: block;"></div>`

although it does not show the fancybox

Comment: also during the second call - when i click an image the first time - the pointer changes to arrow for the whole of the page - suggesting that the fancybox does get loaded but does not show up..


also i AM able to open a fancy as many times on the same page...

Comment: can you show us what is in load data?

Comment: @jeremy-warne : I don't see how this question can be answered since the OP is not providing any further feedback. I think some code is missing like the rendered html after the ajax call. My guess? this is an implementation error rather than fancybox not supporting dynamically added elements. If you have a similar issue (and the reason you offered the bounty) then I would advice you to open your own question with your specific issues.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you are using ajax to bring up your content after the first fancybox request, which means that your jquery commands becomes irrelevant to the dynamic content.

To make them relevant you need to use a "listening" method, that will respond to your to your dynamic content actions:

Presuming your jQuery is above 1.7, you should use the [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method with your fancybox. should be something like this:

```
$(".fancybox").on("click", function(){
   $(this).fancybox();
});
```

There are nicer ways to do that, but that one should work.

Comment: `your jquery commands becomes irrelevant to the dynamic content` Not true, fancybox 2 supports dynamically added content. Also, your `.on()` click code doesn't trigger fancybox, only binds fancybox to the selector http://jsfiddle.net/TRkVJ/

Answer (score 0):

1. first, create a generic container wrapper for your product and wrapper.
2. name it something unique like "product-container-{id}", replacing {id} with a custom numeric unique value
3. when you load a new product via ajax, instead of replacing the content check if "#product-container-{requested-id}" exists
4. if it exists, hide every "product-container-{id}" element and unhide the requested element "#product-container-{requested-id}"
   if it does not exist, create a new container "#product-container-{requested-id}" and initiate jquery fancybox in that folder like this: $("#product-container-{requested-id} .fancybox").fancybox();
5. now you should have a small ajax cache for the already loaded elements within a session, without breaking functionality

Comment: With fancybox v2.x you don't need to initiate fancybox but once since that version works with existing or dynamically added elements. See this answer from the plugin's author http://stackoverflow.com/a/11101122/1055987

Comment: sorry but I didn't use fancybox since v1.x so I didn't know :D

Answer (score 0):

So from what i understood your fancy box not working after the second element that inserted in the div. For that you have to reinitialize the **facncybox** for those elements .

On the success function you have to reinitialize **facncybox** like this

```
$('div#type1_link').on('click',function() {         
    $('div#ajax_div').html("<img src='ajax-load.gif' />").load("type1.php?carmodel=" + $for_url,function(){
        $(".fancybox").fancybox();//This initialized for dynamic content
    });
});
```

you should also check that your dynamic content also have those correct attributes of fancy box and necessary initialization for different types of jquery binding.

Comment: With fancybox v2.x you don't need to initiate fancybox but once since that version works with existing or dynamically added elements. See this answer from the plugin's author http://stackoverflow.com/a/11101122/1055987