# Fancybox 2 malfunction, or solved?

Tags: html, function, fancybox, call, loaded

I use fancybox 2 to overlays, and after using fancybox 1 for a long time, there is a weird thing in v2.
In v1, if I loaded new html via ajax, with new fancybox link in it, I had to call fancybox again for the new link.
In v2, it seems that after new html is loaded, new fancybox works without calling the function again. However, I don't see any prove if it works that way in v2, neither in source code, nor on the web. In the future, I don't want troubles with fancybox, so I had to be sure of it, before continuing work.

Thanks

Comment: fancybox v1.3.x didn't support dynamically added elements so you were needing workarounds like this http://stackoverflow.com/a/9084293/1055987. With fancybox v2.x you don't need any workaround and you can work with existing or dynamically added elements since that version uses `live`. see this answer from the plugin's author http://stackoverflow.com/a/11101122/1055987

Comment: Thanks, so it's sure for me now. But where can I find this in fancybox 2 source code?

Comment: You find it here http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#license

Comment: Oh, I was just blind! Thanks!